# Conditions for $A\cos^2(x)+B\sin^2(x)+C\sin(x)\cos(x)+D\cos(x)+E\sin(x)+F = 0$ to have (a) real root(s)

Tags: trigonometry

I am doing research on Linear Algebra and encounter a function in the form like below:
$$A\cos^2(x)+B\sin^2(x)+C\sin(x)\cos(x)+D\cos(x)+E\sin(x)+F = 0$$
What are the conditions that the coefficients of the equation need to satisfy for it to have (a) real root(s)? I am just wondering if there are some known results for the problem.

Comment: The equation transforms into a quartic. (See, for instance, [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4495592/409). I'm sure there are others on the site, as well.) There is [a formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots) for the roots, but it's complicated. In any case: the equation is "always" solvable in the abstract. (Some roots may be non-real.)

Comment: Thank you! I should have added that the roots need to be real.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to view the situation is that you are solving a system of two equations
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$
The first is just the unit circle, and using linear algebra you can show the second is a conic section if it's not empty or a single point (so a parabola, line, hyperbola, ellipse, or a circle). So you're asking for the number of intersection points for this circle and conic section. It can be anywhere between $0$ and $4$ depending on the exact scenario.

How to find exactly how many and their values is an annoying calculation. One thing that can help is to rotate coordinates so that $C = 0$, and then solve the new equations directly. I believe you get a quartic equation whose roots determine the exact solutions and how many of them are real.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your specific problem (such as those specific coefficients), and maybe you can try this:

Method.1: (delicate)

This is a quadratic form, and you can use eigenvalue-eigenvector method to transform it into a standard form (get rid of linear terms and cross terms), so find the transformation matrix.

Method.2: (brute)

Let $y=\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-y^2}$, and the equation goes to:

$$\pm(Cy+D)\sqrt{1-y^2}=-A(1-y^2)-By^2-Ey-F$$

Square them on both sides and use solution formula for $4$-th order polynomial.

Comment: Method 2 seems to be really complicated. I found the Wikipedia page of the quartic function. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) The expressions for the roots are quite long. Also, the root, y, needs to be less or equal to 1 since y = sin(x) in our case.

Comment: Right, so it depends on the specific problem. @RunzeLi

Comment: FYI, the quartic polynomial works out to

$$(A^2 - 2AB + B^2 + C^2)y^4 + 2(BE - AE + CD)y^3 + (2AB + 2BF + D^2 + E^2 - 2A^2 - C^2 - 2AF)y^2 + 2(AE + EF - CD)y + (A^2 + 2AF + F^2 - D^2) = 0$$

And you don't need to explicitly solve for the roots; just show that one exists in the interval [-1, 1].

Answer (score 1):

The conic section given in Zarrax's answer,

$$Ax^2 + By^2 + Cxy + Dx + Ey + F = 0$$

can be reordered into a simple quadratic in terms of either $x$ or $y$:

$$Ax^2 + (Cy + D)x + (By^2 + Ey + F) = 0$$
$$By^2 + (Cx + E)y + (Ax^2 + Dx + F) = 0$$

Plugging the coefficients into the quadratic formula, we get:

$$x = \frac{-(Cy + D) \pm \sqrt{(Cy + D)^2 - 4A(By^2 + Ey + F)}}{2A}$$
$$y = \frac{-(Cx + E) \pm \sqrt{(Cx + E)^2 - 4B(Ax^2 + Dx + F)}}{2B}$$

In order for a real solution to exist, both discriminants must simultaneously be non-negative, i.e.,

$$(Cy + D)^2 - 4A(By^2 + Ey + F) \ge 0$$
$$(Cx + E)^2 - 4B(Ax^2 + Dx + F) \ge 0$$

We can add these together to get:

$$(Cy + D)^2 - 4A(By^2 + Ey + F) + (Cx + E)^2 - 4B(Ax^2 + Dx + F) \ge 0$$
$$C^2y^2 + 2CDy + D^2 - 4ABy^2 - 4AEy - 4AF + C^2x^2 + 2CEx + E^2 - 4ABx^2 - 4BDx - 4BF \ge 0$$
$$C^2(x^2 + y^2) - 4AB(x^2 + y^2) + (2CE - 4BD)x + (2CD - 4AE)y - 4AF - 4BF + D^2 + E^2 \ge 0$$

But any solution must also lie on the unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, so this simplifies slightly to:

$$C^2 - 4AB + (2CE - 4BD)x + (2CD - 4AE)y - 4AF - 4BF + D^2 + E^2 \ge 0$$
$$(2CE - 4BD)x + (2CD - 4AE)y \ge 4(AB + AF + BF) - (C^2 + D^2 + E^2)$$

Now, define the function:

$$f(\theta) = (2CE - 4BD)\cos(\theta) + (2CD - 4AE)\sin(\theta)$$

Recall that

$$\alpha \cos(\theta) + \beta \sin(\theta) = \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2} \sin(\theta + \tan^{-1}(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}))$$

So the amplitude of the sine wave defined by $f$ is:

$$\sqrt{(2CE - 4BD)^2 + (2CD - 4AE)^2}$$
$$\sqrt{4C^2E^2 - 16BCDE + 16B^2D^2 + 4C^2D^2 - 16ACDE + 16A^2E^2}$$
$$2 \sqrt{C^2E^2 - 4BCDE + 4B^2D^2 + C^2D^2 - 4ACDE + 4A^2E^2}$$
$$2 \sqrt{C^2(D^2 + E^2) + 4(A^2E^2 + B^2D^2) - 4(A + B)CDE}$$

Thus, a necessary condition for the original equation to have real solutions is:

$$2 \sqrt{C^2(D^2 + E^2) + 4(A^2E^2 + B^2D^2) - 4(A + B)CDE} \ge 4(AB + AF + BF) - (C^2 + D^2 + E^2)$$

There's probably a way to simplify this further, though.